# Using function as argument results in "takedamage() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)" error

Tags: python, python-2.7

First of all, beware, first time asker and very new programmer here, the following question and/or code may contain extreme noobness...

I have a function `takedamage(self, accuracy, dmg)` within the class `hostilemelee`. If I give it the arguments "manually" IE:

```
testnpc = hostilemelee()
testnpc.takedamge(5, 20)
```

the function runs fine. But if I use the function `ironman.meleeatack(5)` which returns 2 numbers as the arguments, I get the "Needs exactly 3 arguments" error. 
The `ironman.meleeatack` function is:

```
def meleeattack(self, aggression):   
    accroll = randint(self.maccuracy,100)  
    powerroll = randint(self.strength,100)
    meleedmg = (powerroll * (1 + aggression / 10)) 
    if randint(0, 15) < aggression:
        dmg = 0
    else:
        dmg = meleedmg + self.bdamage
    return accroll, dmg
```

And the `testnpc.takedamage` function is:

```
    def takemdamage(self, accuracy, dmg):
    if dmg == 0:
        print "Ironman's attack misses!" 
        self.dmgmitigated = 0
    elif accuracy < self.accreq:
        print "%s evades the attack!" % self.name 
        self.dmgmitigated = "All"
    else:
        self.health = self.health - (.25 * dmg) - .75 * (dmg - \
        (self.armor / 100) * dmg)
        self.dmgmitigated = .75 * (self.armor / 100 * dmg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unpack the result of `meleeattack`.  Try `testnpc.takedamge(*ironman.meleeatack(5))` instead.  Without the asterisk, you are passing a tuple as a single argument, with the asterisk, the interpreter unpacks the values in the tuple in to 2 arguments before passing them to the `takedamage` method.